# How is the basis $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, i),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, -i)\} $ orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, quantum-computation

How are the bases $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, i)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, -i)$ orthonormal? I know for a basis to be orthonormal it must have a dot product of zero and a norm of $1$. Yet, while the dot product of these two vectors is $1$, my textbook lists these bases as orthonormal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex inner product uses the conjugate of one of the vectors so ignoring the scalars we have that $(1,i) \cdot (1,-i) = 1 + i^2=0$ because the conjugate of $-i$ is $i$.

Comment: A place to look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Real_and_complex_numbers  Physicists may put the conjugate on the left-hand argument, whereas mathematicians may put it on the right.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that without taking the conjugate, the "inner product" of $(1, i)$ with itself is zero, which means that it's not even an inner product.